# Embeding custom font for telugu in android is not working

Tags: android

```
Typeface typeface = 
 Typeface.createFromAsset(myContext.getAssets(), "fonts/gauthami.ttf");
```

I am using this statement in my android project and i copied `gauthami.ttf` file in my assets/fonts folder.It is not working.What might be the problem.

If i remove this ttf file blank page is coming.But when i keep this file telugu is not rendering properly.

Thanks in advance...